# redis - display values less than $foo

Tags: laravel, redis, timestamp

I'm making a simple news website in laravel. I'm almost there, but I would like to add a trending articles option with help of redis. My question is - is there an option in redis to display results with value less than a variable foo. To be more exact, i've added timestamp and id in a hash, and i would like to display only results with timestamp-84600.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it would be to also add them to a sorted set and then use [zrangebyscore](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to access them.

So you'd add

```
ZADD articletimes <time> articleID
```

to redis and then

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE articletimes <time-84600> <time>
```

to get your results back.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you proposed.. so the best way, is to use both hashes and sorted set? One of them would act as a pivot table of some kind?

Comment: Yeah you'd use the sorted set to get the articleID, and then look up the hash using those. If you wanted to reduce the number of calls you could make a redis-side Lua script that performs both operations at the same time and then returns the result.

Comment: I finally got it! And before midnight :D So. What I did is:

Comment: rrrr, cant edit that previous, pressed enter and it posted :/ anyway, I made a hashed **post_id** with views count, and id and sorted set **postTimes** with timestamps, as you suggested, the question I was supposed to ask was, how to SORT through both sets! So I did something like this: 

`sort postTimes by post_*->views get post_*->views DESC limit 0 3`

Comment: again enter, sorry bout that.. so now I only have to figure out if there is a `where` option in sort. The thing I forgot  to mention in my question, was that I am looking for two params at same time: 3 post in last week _with most views_